# Excel VBA: In a loop, why am I losing my active workbook when I evaluate another sub?

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am modifying a function for looping through all workbooks in a folder and performing an action on each.

In the code below, if I un-comment the `Module1.TestSub` line, the loop performs TestSub on each file in the chosen folder, as expected.

But I want it to work as a function, taking another sub or function as it's argument and performing that on the loop, so that I could run `LoopThroughWorkbooks (Module1.TestSub)` and not have to edit LoopThroughWorkbooks every time I want to loop a different action.

If I instead un-comment the `Evaluate (myAction)` line, it seems to still loop through the intended files doing nothing, and performs `Module1.TestSub` on the file I had active to begin with.

It seems like the `Evaluate (myAction)` line is losing track of the workbook opened by the loop in a way that doesn't happen when I just explicitly call `Module1.TestSub`.

```
Function LoopThroughWorkbooks(myAction As String)
'PURPOSE: To loop through all xls* files in a user specified folder and perform an action
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim myPath As String
 Dim myFile As String
 Dim myExtension As String
 Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
 Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
   With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
     If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
     myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
   End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
 myPath = myPath
 If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
 myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
 myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
 Do While myFile <> ""
  'Set variable equal to opened workbook
   Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

  'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
   DoEvents

  'Do Action Specified in Argument
   'Module1.TestSub <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< This line works

   'Evaluate (myAction) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< This line doesn't

  'Save and Close Workbook
   wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

  'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
   DoEvents

  'Get next file name
   myFile = Dir

 Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
 MsgBox "Looping Complete!"

'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
ResetSettings:
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

And in case it's helpful, here's Module1.TestSub:

```
Function TestSub()

Range("A1") = "AAA"

End Function
```

And here's how I'm calling it:

```
Sub runtest()

Module2.LoopThroughWorkbooks (Module1.TestSub)

End Sub
```

Comment: Change [`Evaluate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-evaluate-method-excel) to [`Application.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220716(v=office.11).aspx), and change `(Module1.TestSub)` to `"Module1.TestSub"` - because `Module1.TestSub` is not a Function, it doesn't return anything, so your `MyAction` string will be blank (check that with `Debug.Print myAction`)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, @Chronocidal !